# Doubt in the definition of arc length of a circle

Tags: definition, mathematics, geometry

The definition of the angle in terms of radians is the ratio of the arc length divided by the radius. In other words:
$$\theta =\frac{\ell}{r}$$
Suppose we have two homocentric circles as in the picture. In order to this definition to make sense the ratio of the two arc lengths to their corresponding radius must be equal. In general we don't know how much of the circumference is each arc, so:

$$\theta_1=\frac{aC_1}{r_1}$$
$$\theta_2=\frac{bC_2}{r_2}$$
and $$r_2=λ r_1$$
where $C$ is the circumference.

How can we proove that $θ_1=θ_2=θ$ or $a=b$ ? Otherwise it doesn't make sense to measure the angle in radians (as ratio of lengths).

[image: Homocentric circles]

Comment: Will you accept that $s_1$ is the same fraction of the full circumference of the smaller circle that $s_2$ is of the larger circle?

Comment: @ThePhoton Why to accept it. It seems to be the same but "seems" is not appropriate for mathematics.

Comment: There is only one angle.  How can it have two different values?

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas, every mathematical system starts with some axioms or postulates that must be accepted without proof. I'm trying to figure out which ones you want to work with here.

Comment: what exactly is you starting hypothesis? What are you trying to prove?Are you accepting the definition of the radian and then trying to prove that the angles are equal via a construction that assumes so in the first place?  Or are you trying to prove the definition of radian via some construction in which the angles *would have been* different?

Comment: In non-Euclidean geometries you do not have $\theta=\theta_1=\theta_2$. Gauss was the first to recognise that the geometry of space may not be Euclidean, and Einstein used non-Euclidean geometry in general relativity.

Comment: @lineage I don't have problem to accept the definition. What I am asking is how we know it is consistent if we examine different circles? I mean when we have 1 circle we measure the ratio and this is the angle. How we know if we extend the radius of that circle that the ratio will also be the same?

Comment: @S.McGrew What I want to know if the ratios are the same. The angle of course is.

Comment: That's because $ l$ is proportional to $r$

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks for the answer. I don't understand why arcs of homocentric circles which subtend the same angle must have the same ratio of arc length divided by the corresponding radius. If I can prove this the I don't have problem to accept the definition.

Comment: You remember that the circumference is given by $2\pi r$, right? And if $\theta=\pi/2$, for example, then the subtended arc must be 1/4 of the circumference. Or if $\theta=\pi/12$ then the arc must be 1/24 of the circumference, and so on. Are you okay with that argument so far?

Comment: This is a trivial question in plane geometry.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes.

Comment: If the angles are the same, and the centers of the circular arcs are concentric, then yes: the angles drawn similarly with respect to the two portions of the figure are themselves are the same.  " similar" in this contwxt means the angles and proportions of the line segments.  To realize why this applies to the figure you've presented, try writing down step-by-step instructions and asking zomeone to follow instructions withput any additipnal help.

Answer (score 1):

We certainly cannot prove it in general. In non-Euclidean geometries you do not have $\theta=\theta_1=\theta_2$. Gauss was the first to recognise that the geometry of space may not be Euclidean, and Einstein used non-Euclidean geometry in general relativity.

To prove it you would need an equivalent axiom. Euclid included the parallel postulate in his axioms, which will make it provable, but it is now known that the parallel postulate does not hold for the geometry of space.

This is easily seen from the fact that clocks on GPS satellites do not keep time with identical clocks on the surface of the Earth. Since the local speed of light is everywhere the same, it follows that the circumference of a circular orbit is not equal to $2\pi R$.

In Euclidean geometry you could prove it by dividing the sectors into many similar triangles.